# Prove 2 segments in complex plane have the same length

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I saw a solution which stated that we simultaneously show that two segments in the complex plane $A$ and $B$ have the same length and are perpendicular if we can show that $B=iA$.
I get that the rotation by $i$ implies they're perpendicular but why does showing this imply they're of the same length?

Comment: One of my rules in complex analysis is if I have a problem that I don't have a better approach to, I write $z=x+iy$ and see where that leads.  That would work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x,y$ be the endpoints of $A$; so $ix,iy$ are the endpoints of $B$ (here, $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$). In the complex plane, the length of $A$ is just $|y - x|$; the length of $B$ is then:
$$|iy - ix| = |i(y - x)| = |i| |y - x| = |y-x|.$$